# create a selector widget in django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-widget

I want to create a form widget like the permission selector in the admin page.

The model where i want to choose the records is a view from the database

```
class Ftp_Archivo(models.Model):
      id_lista = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
      id_proveedor = models.IntegerField()
      codigo_asignado = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Codigo Asignado')
      nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)
      archivo = models.CharField(max_length=500)

      class Meta:
            managed=False
            db_table='pc_archivos_no_migrados'
```

I want to save the records in this model:

```
class PYC_Archivo(models.Model):
      id_archivo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      id_proveedor =  models.ForeignKey(Proveedor,db_column='id_proveedor',verbose_name='Proveedor')
      codigo_asignado = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Codigo Asignado')
      nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)
      archivo = models.CharField(max_length=500)
      fecha_migracion = models.DateField(auto_now = True,verbose_name='Fecha Migracion')
```

I don't know if is possible use a widget like the permission selector in admin page and which widget I need to use in my form.

Comment: What is a 'selector widget'? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I search and I find it. Is called FilteredSelectMultiple widget

Answer (score 3):

I got it

I need to import the widget from admin.widgets and add the proper css and js files like this in the definition of the form

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class fileform(forms.Form):
    archivos = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Proveedor.objects.all(),required=True,
               widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Proveedor",is_stacked=False))
 class Media:
        css = {
            'all':('/admin/css/widgets.css',),
        }
        # jsi18n is required by the widget
        js = ('/admin/jsi18n/',)
```

and in the template is necessary call the media files

```
{{form.media}}
```